# PHP: get derived class context in static function? i.e. differ between BaseClass::staticBaseFunc() vs DerivedClass::staticBaseFunc()

Tags: php, self, derived-class, static-classes, static-functions

I have a base class with a static function. But I would like to have a way to know the actual class (could be the base class or a derived class) within whose context I am calling the static function.

For example:

```php
<?php

class Foo
{
    static function Test() 
    { 
        $c = self::class;
        echo "Hello, I am creating a new instance of type $c";
        return new $c;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo 
{
    public $someProperty;
}

$b = Bar::Test(); // This should do something different than Foo::Test();

?>
```

Note that the `self::class` in the `Test()` function always results in `'Foo'` even if I'm calling it using the `Bar::` context.

I understand I could override the `Test()` function in `Bar` but that's not what I want, I want to keep the implemented functionality in the base `Test()` function. But just with the actual static class context that I'm calling it with.

Is there a way for the above `Test()` function to say "I am creating a new instance of type **Bar**" and return a `Bar` instance, rather than a `Foo` ?

Comment: Read about [instanceof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks, I was aware of `instanceof` however unless I misunderstood, that only applies to *instances* (i.e. objects) whereas I am calling a static class function (i.e. no object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me introduced you to late static binding.

Consider the following code, it's not exactly like yours but it highlight's the issue I believe you are facing.

```
<?php

class A 
{

    public static $string = 'I am from class A';

    public static function getString()
    {
        return self::$string;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static $string = 'I am from class B';
}

B::getString(); // returns 'I am from class A' ???!
?>
```

To get around this you can use late static binding to use the variable at run time context (rather than at compile time context)

```
<?php

class A 
{

    public static $string = 'I am from class A';

    public static function getString()
    {
        return static::$string; // note the change here
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static $string = 'I am from class B';
}

B::getString(); // returns 'I am from class B' and all is well 
?>
```

Far more information than I can give you is available here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: I hope I understood your issue , I feel like I didn't!

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the concept of late static binding but wasn't aware of how it works in php. The link in your comment contained just what I needed: within the `Foo::Test()` function, instead of `self::class` I had to use `get_called_class()` [(manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/function.get-called-class.php) and now it works exactly as intended! Calling `Foo::Test()` will create a `Foo`, calling `Bar::Test()` creates a `Bar`! 

Comment: Brilliant stuff